# Why does Google Chrome still support __proto__?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

`__proto__` is deprecated. Why do big browsers like Google Chrome still use it? Are there any plans to dump it?

Comment: Probably for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I'd personally try to use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` in its place for getting. Unfortunately there's no current way to set like `__proto__` offers.

Comment: A shim for browser that don't support `getPrototypeOf` for browsers that don't support it could be: `function( obj ) { return obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype; };`. Not perfect, but should cover most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the hardest thing to do in a language / framework is actually remove a deprecated feature.  There is still loads of code in the world which depends on this feature.  Removing it **will** break websites.  Chrome has apparently looked at the cost of maintenance vs. the pain /cost of removal and chosen maintenance.

Comment: Chrome supports `document.all`! Talk about a deprecated feature :)

Answer (score 2):

`__proto__` is not only deprecated, it was actually never part of the standard. Removing the feature from Chrome would mean that some pages would no longer work in Chrome, and there is no reason to break these pages.

The feature has been added to JavaScript (ECAMScript 5) as the 'getPrototypeOf' function, and new JavaScript programs should use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

A **proto** pseudo property has been included in §B.3.1 of the draft ECMAScript ed. 6 specification (note that the specification codifies what is already in implementations and what webites may currently rely on).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto